# Imacros little help required

Tags: imacros

Hi I wanna scrap url from http://www.yelp.com/biz/pooka-pure-and-simple-orange-2#query:business but when I played script its not giving me the output in output file at location {{!COL2}}.

Please help.Your special consideration will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE 130.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:bizUrl:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=130.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will not work like this because of several reasons:

1. you can't save result to currently used source file
2. even if you can it will other-write data in first column and not in second
3. your source file has only one column because of SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
4. you are using * in file path so it will use standard download folder specified in the Paths tab of the Options dialog and not Datasources default folder used for source file.

Comment: I am new to it can you suggest how it should looks like?

Comment: I have also tried this one but so far same issue no data found in result csv file available in my download folder VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE 130.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:bizUrl:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=result.csv

Comment: Currently I have checked but #EANF# value is found as output

Comment: #EANF# - mean that stated tag data is not found on the page